# Android Intent - How to open Instagram DM page?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, instagram

just to clarify about what I mean, I'm talking about the page you get to when swiping left to get to the list of Instagram users to DM.

I have searched around and have not found anyone bringing up what the intent script would be to do so.

Answer (score 1):

this code open Instagram direct message activity:

```
    val intentDirect = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
    intentDirect.setComponent(ComponentName("com.instagram.android","com.instagram.direct.share.handler.DirectShareHandlerActivity"))
    intentDirect.setType("text/plain")
    intentDirect.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Your message here")
    startActivity(intentDirect)
```